# Errors occur when set MySQL ODBC

Tags: mysql, odbc

Errors occur when set MySQL ODBC.

My operating system is win10 x64 and my MySQL Server version is 5.5. My Connector ODBC version is 5.3.

When I establish OBDC, the connection test is successfully, just as the following image.
[image]

However, when I click the "OK" button, there comes an error. The DSN is invalid.
[image]

I have refered some websites and tutorials, but still can not  solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not name your Datasource `ODBC`. Try `Foobar`, or `abc`, it should work. For whatever reason, the string `ODBC` cannot be used as DSN. This does not depend on the driver used.

Comment: Thank you very much. I;ve fixed it.